# Snapping to face doesn't work

Tags: snapping

I"m following BlenderGuru's tutorial for begginers. I'm at [This video] [1] [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jmSgsaNSQ6s&t=2s . But I  can't snap the vertex to the face. I have snap to face, Snap with closest, Prohject onto self, Project Individual elements and Affect closest. In tool > option, i have auto merge. Whatever i do, I can just move the vertex freely.

Can someone help ?

Edit: it seems to only do that when i drag it far from the object, but if it's close, it look like it stick to it. Is this normal ?

Comment: What settings do you see in the Snapping menu under "Snap With"?

Comment: Where is that menu ?

Comment: At the top center of the 3D View window.

Comment: it looks like there's a bug with the snap to face for some platforms or blender versions, at least the question has already been asked